# Media queries and Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, media-queries

I want to change a script when the screen resolution decreases.
I read something about using "screen.width" did not work.

Here is my script code ...

```
    $(function() {    
         $("div.holder").jPages({
             containerID: "itemContainer",
             keyBrowse   : true,
             perPage : 5     
         }); 
    });
```

For example, I want only two posts appear when the screen resolution is less than 600 pixels.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [documentation for the screen object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.screen). You may also need a [resize handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onresize) if you want the # of posts to change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.innerWidth to get the size of the window. Your example modified to support this:

```
$(function() {    
     $("div.holder").jPages({
         containerID: "itemContainer",
         keyBrowse   : true,
         perPage : (window.innerWidth < 600 ? 2 : 5)     
     }); 
});
```

Comment: Great job, Joshua!

But my intention was that it would change automatically, without refresh the page. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: As noted by braican you can listen for for the resize event on the window object.

Answer (score 0):

you could attach a handler to the `resize` event. Since it seems you're using jQuery:

```
$(function() {    
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID: "itemContainer",
        keyBrowse   : true,
        perPage : 5     
    }); 

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(window.innerWidth < 600){
            // change perPage to 2 here
        }
    });
});
```

docs for jQuery's .resize() method - http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a resize event handler, like braican mentioned. However, I would recommend tying it up with [Throttle](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce).

The other option would be to use [mediaCheck](https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck) (which is just a wrapper around matchMedia).